# Nginx not loading other sites after enabled SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx

Here is my `/etc/sites-available/default`

```
server {
    listen    443 default_server;
    server_name _;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/example/example.com.key;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

The first block is what I've added recently. I host multiple sub-domains on this server. This is an example of `sites-available/my.example.com`:

```
server {
    server_name my.example.com;

    access_log /var/data/log/nginx/my.example.com.log;
    error_log  /var/data/log/nginx/my.example.com.log;

    root       /var/data/www/lmy.example.com/htdocs;
    index      index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Whenever I used to go to `http://my.example.com`, the website would load fine. But now, going to `https://my.example.com` just goes to the default page. The `my.example.com` file is symlinked from `sites-enabled`. The config seems fine, because if I comment the line `return 301 ...` from the `port 80` block, `http://my.example.com` works again, but `https://my.example.com` shows the default nginx page.

Comment: The above config only has `http://my.example.com`. Where is the config for `https://my.example.com`? [This may help you](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)

Comment: Yup, you're right. I added a `listen 443` to the block and it worked. Thanks :)